# Effect of the length $\ell$ on a pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, time, oscillators

Currently, I am trying to intuitively understand how the length $\ell$ affects the period of a pendulum. I understand that the shorter the length $\ell$, the shorter the time period $T$. When we have a pendulum, doesn't the top move slower than the bottom, as it covers less distance in the same amount of time? So when we have a longer pendulum, the bottom should move faster and therefore have a shorter period $T$. Obviously, this is incorrect, so how does it actually work?

Comment: https://www.studysmarter.co.uk/explanations/physics/oscillations/period-of-pendulum/

Answer (score 1):

> When we have a pendulum, doesn't the top move slower than the bottom,
> as it covers less distance in the same amount of time?

You are writing about the string not the pendulum bob.

Consider a simple pendulum at rest when displaced at an angle $\theta$ from the vertical.
The torque $\tau$ about the point of suspension due to the gravitational force $mg$ will produce an angular acceleration $\alpha$ given by $\tau = I_{\rm suspension} \,\alpha \Rightarrow m\,g\,\sin \theta \,\ell= m\, \ell^2\,\alpha$ where $\ell$ is the length of the pendulum.

You will note that as the length of the string increases so does the torque, $\propto \ell$, but the moment of inertia (a measure of reluctance to undergo angular acceleration) increases more, $\propto \ell^2$, so the angular acceleration of a longer pendulum is less and hence its period is greater.

You can apply a similar argument in terms of the accelerating force, $m\,g\,\sin \theta$, and hence the linear acceleration being the same at a given angle $\theta$ but the shorter pendulum bob has to travel a smaller distance and so tahes a shorter period of time to complete an oscillation.